# Rails 3 - Adding method to Array class in environment.rb causes error with objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have recently come upon an error when I added the following to my environment.rb file:

```
class Array
  def sum
    self.inject{|sum,x| sum + x }
  end
end
```

The intended method, which allows me to do array.sum, works perfectly, but it has caused a strange error when I try to access objects via a given objects `has_many` relationship, for example:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :device_abilities, :abilities

  has_many :device_abilities, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :abilities, :through => :device_abilities, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Ability < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :device_abilities, :devices

  has_many :device_abilities, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :devices, :through => :device_abilities, :dependent => :destroy
end

class DeviceAbility < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :device_id, :ability_id

  belongs_to :device
  belongs_to :ability
end
```

This works fine without the sum method in environment.rb, so I can do `@device.abilities` as normal, but when the sum method is added in environment.rb, i get the following error when trying to do `@device.abilities`:

```
undefined method `zero?' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anyone suggest why this is happening, and how I can work around it? I know that i can sum each array manually, but this doesn't seem very rails-esque.

Thanks!

Comment: To sum a field of an AR model instance Rails provides http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M000296 could you that instead of adding sum to Array?

Comment: Also note that the "arrays" returned from AR relationships aren't arrays, even though they claim they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sum is already defined by rails as [Enumerable#sum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum), so you shouldn't have to define it at all.

Also, I don't think environment.rb is the right place to put this sort of thing. You should create a new initializer file if you want to extend base classes. Your new method is probably interfering with rails' version of it.